# 404 error during ugly url redirect to pretty url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tried a lot of examples on StackOverflow but nothing seems to work in my case.

my URL is - https://apkleet.com/apk.php?app=google-camera
and I want to redirect it to this - https://apkleet.com/apk/google-camera

I am successful in creating a pretty URL by this htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^apk/(.*)$ ./apk.php?app=$1
```

---

after adding this code in .htaccess file user can access both pretty and ugly URLs which have a negative effect on SEO that why I decided to redirect the ugly URL to a pretty URL by using this code.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^app=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^apk\.php$ /apk/%1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^apk/([^-]+)$ /apk.php?app=$1 [L]
```

and the redirection works but the problem is that I am getting 404 error. what is the problem? how i will correct my code? help me...

Comment: Question seems to missing access and rewrite log. Or an explanation on how `([^-]+)` should match `google-camera`.

Comment: _“which have a negative effect on SEO”_ - then specify the proper _canonical URL_ in the result page, and be done with it …

Comment: You may find it easier to always implement `redirect to the right url, if on the wrong one` in your application logic. Otherwise apache rules get more complicated than necessary. The apache logic can then be limited to "make sure this request gets to the right place".

Comment: bro why I should add canonical if the better way is available.

Comment: @AD7six can you show me some example

Comment: @mario can you show me how i will correct this

Comment: `$correctUrl = application logic defines this; if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== $correctUrl) { header('Location: '. $correctUrl); die; }` something like that. please research any questions you have with this.

Comment: See [How to debug htaccess rewrite script](//stackoverflow.com/q/7738170)

Comment: @AD7six if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1, 7) == 'apk.php'){
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    Header( "Location: https://apkleet.com/apk/".$_GET["app"]);
    exit;
}

Comment: is above code is the right method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to my question is

```
if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1, 7) == 'apk.php'){
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    Header( "Location: https://apkleet.com/apk/".$_GET["app"]);
    exit;
}
```